# Length of list formed from sentences of paragraph

Tags: python

I have following code:

```
def splitParagraphIntoSentences(paragraph):
    import re
    sentenceEnders = re.compile('[.!?]')
    sentenceList = sentenceEnders.split(paragraph)
    return sentenceList

sentenceList=splitParagraphIntoSentences (u"""I have a bicycle. I want the car.
""")
print len(sentenceList)
```

Python will return that the lenght of sentencelist is 3. Actually there are just two sentences. I know i t is so because the '.' at the end of second sentence. What is the best way to teach program count sentences in correct way without removing '.' from the end of second sentence?

Thank you

Comment: `len(re.findall(r'[.!?]', "I have a bicycle. I want the car."))`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting, count the ends:

```
len(sentenceEnders.findall(paragraph))
```

Or subtract 1 to account for the empty line after the last sentence split:

```
len(splitParagraphIntoSentences(paragraph)) - 1
```

or return a filtered list, removing empty items:

```
return filter(None, sentenceList)
```

or, when using Python 3 (where `filter()` returns a generator):

```
return [s for s in sentenceList if s]
```

Comment: Taking one is going to give zero for empty strings as well as potentially valid sentences that just don't happen to have a `.` or similar. If the OP purely wanted to correct the `re.split` then possibly add an `(?!$)`

Comment: But how do you create correct list from the paragraph. I mean list which only contains sentences.